# Butterworth filter python

Tags: python, filter, fft, wav, butterworth

I want to filter a `wav` file with butterworth bandpass. I've tried to convert the `wav` file to `fft` then to apply band-pass filter and then to apply `ifft`. From the graphics it seems to be a little filtered but when I lessen to both input and output `wav` there is no difference in audio, it is like the filter it`s not working. Is there a mistake?

```
# FFT - Fast Fourier Transform
frequency,data = wavfile.read('Input_sound.wav')
signalFFT = fft(data)
def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, frequency, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * frequency
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq

    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandpass')
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y 
funct=butter_bandpass_filter(signalFFT,2100,3400,44100,4)

filtered_sound=ifft(funct)
filtered_sound=sp.real(filtered_sound)
filtered_sound=sp.int16(filtered_sound/sp.absolute(filtered_sound).max()*32767)
wavfile.write('Filtered_ouput.wav',frequency,filtered_sound)
```

Comment: I have never used `butter` and `lfilter`, but as I understand the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) the `lfilter` might be applied to your `data` and not `signalFFT`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the exemple of the `lfilter` [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html), it seems that you don't need to perform FFT, but directly provide the `data` to the filter. It is then much simpler

```py
frequency,data = wavfile.read('Input_sound.wav')

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, frequency, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * frequency
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq

    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandpass')
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y 

filtered_sound=butter_bandpass_filter(data,2100,3400,44100,4)
wavfile.write('Filtered_ouput.wav',frequency,filtered_sound)
```